# How to map the features into all polynomial terms of x₁ and x₂ up to the sixth power

Tags: mapping, polynomials, coursera-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svlI6.png)
This is from the Coursera Supervised Machine Learning: Regression and Classificationby Andrew Ng, week 3 practice lab.
X₁¹
X₂¹
X₁²
X₁¹X₂¹
X₂²
X₁³
X₁²X₂¹
X₁¹X₂²
X₂³
X₁⁴
X₁³X₂¹
X₁²X₂²
X₁¹X₂³
X₂⁴
X₁⁵
X₁⁴X₂¹
X₁³X₂²
X₁²X₂³
X₁¹X₂⁴
X₂⁵
X₁⁶
X₁⁵X₂¹
X₁⁴X₂²
X₁³X₂³
X₁²X₂⁴
X₁¹X₂⁵
X₂⁶

Below is how the 27 dimensional vectory is made. I wanted to figure out how it was made but couldn't find anything online so I figured it by hand and calculator.